# An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (4800000)

Tags: android, developer-console

I accessed to the API access of Google play developer console, because I want to set up Publishing API. But the error in the title has occurred, so I can't continue the setup.

[image]

Comment: so I guess it´s a console problem and you should follow "please try again later"....

Comment: Thanks reply. Yes, I thoght so, and I tried again later(after 1day and 1week) , but it can't change.

Comment: I think you should contact google support. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en&rd=1#contact=1&topic=3450769  In the past sometimes it happened with error code 4800001, and it has been fixed in a view days.

Comment: Thanks your advice. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted google support from bellow url as Opiatefuchs said, then it has been fixed in a few days.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs?hl=ja&ec=bugs&cfsi=bugs_cf&cfnti=escalationflow.email&cft=3

[image]