# unable to add new game in developer console

Tags: android, google-play-games

I had only one game which is published, but I want to add 2 more games to the developer console. However, I'm getting this error:

[image]

I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not Google Customers Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a pretty common problem.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/play/TYsYfWnHLPg/yrohQUSHAAAJ

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/ITFC8XNl5DU;context-place=forum/play

[An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (4800000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139627/an-unexpected-error-occurred-please-try-again-later-4800000)

I think the best course of action would be to wait until tomorrow and try again (unless the matter is urgent), and if the issue doesn't resolve itself, [contact developer support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/#topic=3364260).

Comment: but can you tell me why this is happening

Comment: No idea what the cause of the issue is. The third link I provided in my answer says it's a console problem, with no further elaboration. I don't really think there's any way to know other than contacting support.

Comment: sir one more question i want to ask. can i delete my publish game from developer console permanently with achievement and leaderboard?

Comment: See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console).

Comment: this is tricky one my game publish in game service but not in all applications section.